# breadth and depth first traversal on a trie

Tags: stack, queue, breadth-first-search, trie

I am trying to output a string representation of the depth first traversal and another string of the breadth first traversal on a trie. So far, my methods only return null and I am not sure why they do not work properly.
This is my method for breadth first traversal:

```
String bfs() {
    Queue<TrieNode> queue = new LinkedList<TrieNode>();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    if(root == null) {
        System.out.println("Empty trie");
    }
    queue.clear();
    queue.add(root);
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
        TrieNode node = queue.remove();
        builder.append(node.s);
    }
    String result = builder.toString();
    return result;
}
```

My depth first traversal method is similar but it uses stack instead of queue.

Comment: A. Please post [mcve] so we don'y have to guess (for example guessing that `node.s` is the string representation of `node`). Include test data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add node's neighbors to the queue :

```
while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    TrieNode node = queue.remove();
    builder.append(node.s);
    //add node neighbors to queue //<<<<<<missing 
}
```